# Can not Setup Google Chromecast on Ubuntu 14.04 (Chrome extension -> Set up a new Cast device doesn't work)

Tags: 14.04, networking, google-chrome, chromecast

I have searched for hours with google and askubuntu.com but I have no solution found for setup google chromecast on ubuntu 14.04. When I go in the google chrome extension under options and then "Set up new Cast device" searched the extension forever but google chromecast doesn't appear. When I look under my available wireless networks I see the chromecast but chrome cast extension find it not.

My smart phone is defect an I can not setup with my smart phone.

Please help me.

Greetings,
Sven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 2017-01-19, it is not possible to setup a Chromecast device from Linux.  It has to be done through the other supported devices.  Unfortunately, Google's engineers could not come up with a software stack that would be shared among multiple OSs.

However, once the Chromecast device has been setup, it works nicely within Linux.  I suggest that you borrow a supported device from someone you know to proceed.